# How to get my app download details besides Apple developer account

Tags: ios, app-store

I know from the Apple developer account we can get how much downloads have done for our particular app. Now our clients asking they want to check the apps downloads without involving developers. Is there any way to find those details besides from the appstore, or else without accessing the developer account

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the iOS App Store and not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually see your download numbers in itunesconnect and therefore you can just invite your clients to look into the data there. There are also a number of web services that use the data from itunesconnect to show more details, for instance app statistics.

If you want more data and even logging, many users integrate additional logging features in their apps like google analytics for instance.

If this is not what you are looking for, please give me some more information on what you are trying to accomplish!

Comment: Thanks for the answer,, Ho can I use Google analytics,, Do I ned to do additional something to the app?

Comment: add the SDK [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/) and sign up with google

Comment: As Shams said, you need to integrate this SDK into your app! And you should update the Terms of Service of your app and let your users know if you decide to monitor more than just the download numbers. At least in countries like Germany this is an important legal issue!